# what is the difference between $\tan^2 (x)$ and $\tan(x^2)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I know $\tan^2(x) \neq \tan(x^2)$ but I can't find an intuitive way to understand $\tan^2(x)$. When I do it in my mind I think: $\tan^2(x) = \left(\frac{\text{opp}}{\text{adj}}\right)^2$ which I think isn't right, that looks more like $\tan(x^2)$.

Thanks for any tips, this has been rolling in my head for a while.

Comment: It’s the difference between first squaring and then finding the tangent, and first finding the tangent and then squaring the result. The “in your mind” is correct; it does not look like $\tan(x^2)$, because that would require you to *square the size of the angle*, thus moving to a different triangle before taking the tangent.

Comment: It's just composing function in different order, if $g(x) = tan(x)$, and $f(x) = x^2$ then $ f(g(x)) = f(tan(x)) = (tan(x))^2 = tan^2(x)$, and $g(f(x)) = g(x^2) = tan(x^2)$, so in $tan^2(x)$ you firstly compute $tan(x)$ for a fixed x, then raise it to the power of two, and opposite in $tan(x^2)$ you firstly raise x to the power of two, ten plug it into tangent function.

Comment: @DominikKutek You should post your comment as an official answer.

Comment: The traditional notation is a bit confusing: $\tan^2$ is used to denote the function that takes the tangent of its argument and then squares the result. I.e., $\tan^2(x) = (\tan(x))^2$. If you think about $(\tan(x))^2$, it may be easier to understand.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin You should post your comment as an official answer.

Comment: Any answer should include the point that $\tan^2$ and similar notations are special for the trigonometric functions. $f^2(x)$ usually means $f(f(x))$.

Comment: Related with @RobArthan's comment, for every function $f$, $f^2(x)$ means compute $f(x)$ for some $x$ and then plug into $f$ again: $f^2(x)=f\Big(f(x)\Big)$. But I don't know way, for trigonometric (and maybe for hyperbolic functions), $f^2(x)$ means $\Big(f(x)\Big)^2$, but it is an exception (PD: My comment was related with the first Rob's comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traditional notation for the trigonometrc functions is that $\tan^2$ is the function that maps an angle to the square of its tangent. If, for a given $x$, $\mathsf{opp}$ (i.e., $\sin(x)$) and $\mathsf{adj}$ (i.e., $\cos(x)$) denote the lengths of the legs of a right-angled triangle with unit hypotenuse that are opposite and adjacent to the angle $x$, then $\tan^2(x)$ is indeed equal to $(\mathsf{opp}/\mathsf{adj})^2$, i.e., $(\tan(x))^2$. Your thinking that this is more like $\tan(x^2)$ is incorrect: we are holding the right-angle triangle fixed and looking at different functions of the lengths of its edges.

In modern notation, $f^2(x)$ usually means $f(f(x))$. So as  $\tan(\tan(x))$ and $(\tan(x))^2$ are certainly not the same function, you need to keep in mind that the convention for trigonometric functions is a special one.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the difference. Consider these operations:

- Hit spot marked X with an axe with a mighty blow
- Put your hand on spot X.

Suppose you do these operations in succession Does the order matter?  In general, functional
composition is not commutative.

Comment: I must say that your example is in beautiful harmony with your nickname.

Answer (score 1):

Define $f(x):=(\tan x)^2,\,g(x):=\tan(\tan x),\,h(x):=\tan (x^2)$ (i.e. if $y=x^2$ then $h(x)=\tan y$). These are all completely different functions.

Either $f$ or $g$ could be denoted $\tan^2 x$; if it means $f$ we're composing the squaring function with the tangent function, while if it means $g$ we're composing the tangent function with itself. The reason the latter can be denoted $\tan^2 x$ is because functions form an associative algebra under composition, for which composition is like a "multiplication" of functions. And if you "multiply" the tangent function by itself, you're "squaring" it.

However, it's a matter of convention that, unless *very* clearly stated otherwise, $\tan^2 x$ refers to $f$ rather than $g$, if only because $f$ is far more likely to come up in a problem than $g$ is. In particular, the squared opposite-to-adjacent ratio is indeed $f$.